# Angular ui-router only runs controller's http.get on page load not state change

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm missing something using UI-Router. In my views it will load the partial & JSON when the page loads. On state change, the partial loads but the console states

*"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"*.

**main.js - config**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .state('main.start', {
        url: '/start',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main/start.html',
        controller : 'startController'
    })
    .state('main.end', {
        url: '/end',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main/end.html',
        controller : 'endController'
    })
//default state
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/start');
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sectionMain = 'partials/main.html';
});
.controller('startController', function($scope, $http) {
    // Get Data
    $http.get('data/start.json').success(function(datafile) {
        $scope.data = datafile;
    });
});
.controller('endController', function($scope, $http) {
    // End Data
    $http.get('data/end.json').success(function(datafile) {
        $scope.data = datafile;
    });
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
    <p>{{ d.heading }}</p>
</div>
```

Again, if I hit refresh on any of the views it loads both the partial and the data.
When I switch via the ui-sref attributes it just loads the partial with the aforementioned error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error you are getting occurs when angular senses an infinite digest loop, because of circular state change. I don't see one in your code right now but that may be something you should look for.

Comment: can you sow sample data returned

Comment: Thanks, I'll look more into circular state change.  I was running out of terms to search for with this situation.  

The data loads properly if you refresh the page (in either view), and it returns the loop error on any state change.